# How to specify a device and iOS version to CocoaPods test target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I've added a test target to my cocoapod using the cocoapods documentation [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/test-specs.html) and I would like to specify the iOS version and/or the device to use for testing.

By default it uses the iOS 8.4 on iPhone 4S. My pod `deployment_target` is iOS 8.0 but I want the tests to run on the latest SDK / phone only.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd be interested to know as well.